# str_replace $v* with a php variable

Tags: php

I got some text in html like this

```
<p>Test test test $v1 $v2 $v3 $v11</p>
```

With PHP I need to replace $v1 $v2 $v3 ... $v9, I don't need to replace $v10 ... $v*****

My problem is when I have $v11 in my text it's replacing $v1 + 1 at the end :

```
$v1 = "here";
...
What I got actually : Test test test $v11 => Test test test here1
I need :Test test test $v11 => Test test test
```

$vars is an array in PHP :

```
$v1 = "here";
$v2 = "";
$v3 = "";
$v4 = "";
$v5 = "";
$v6 = "";
$v7 = "";
$v8 = "";
$v9 = "";
$vars = array($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9);
```

My function

```
function replaceVar($vars, $string)
{
  $stringReplace = '$v';
  $i = 1;
  while ($i <= 9) {
    if(!empty($vars[$i]) && strlen($stringReplace . $i) == 3)
    {
      $string = str_replace('$v' . $i, $vars[$i], $string);
    }
    else
    {
      $string = str_replace('$v' . $i, "", $string);
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return $string;
}
```

Excepted output :
$vars is an array in PHP :

```
$v1 = "here";
$v2 = "";
$v3 = "";
$v4 = "";
$v5 = "";
$v6 = "";
$v7 = "";
$v8 = "";
$v9 = "";
$vars = array($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9);

echo replaceVar($vars, "Test test test $v1 $v2 $v11");
```

Test test test here

Comment: Not clear do you need to get "Test test test here" or "Test test test here here1"

Comment: Actually it's replacing $v11 by content of variable $v1+1, because it's replacing $v1 in $v11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this. Try the following

```
<?php
 $str = '<p>Test test test $v1 $v2 $v3 $v11</p>';

$v1 = "here";
$v2 = "";
$v3 = "";
$v4 = "";
$v5 = "";
$v6 = "";
$v7 = "";
$v8 = "";
$v9 = "";
$vars = array($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9);

echo preg_replace_callback('/\$v(\d)\s/', 
       function($match) use ($vars) { return ($vars[$match[1]-1]) . ' '; },
       $str);
```

Note : `return ($vars[$match[1]-1])` the `-1` is there because your 0th element in the `$vars` array is actually for `$v1`

[Demo Here](https://eval.in/685385)

*Note:* I am assuming there is a space after `&v1` otherwise you may have to change the match and replacement.

Explanation:

`'/\$v(\d)\s/'`
match for $v and a digit and a space

`return ($vars[$match[1]-1]) . ' '`

for each match return the element from `$vars` array with index matched value-1. so if `(\d)` matches 1 it will return `$vars[1-1]`

Comment: I don't understand why but it's working now I just need to delete $v* if they are empty in declaration thanks !

Comment: added a small explanation.

Answer (score 0):

replace your HTML with

```
<p>Test test test %s %s %s</p>
```

then you just have to

```
echo vsprintf($string, [$v1, $v2, $v3]);
```

Comment: I can't because it's html imported from DB :)